# Accessing to service by name

Tags: rest, docker, docker-swarm

I am a beginner in swarm and I have some troubles with accessing to service from host by name of service.

My steps:

1) Creating 1 manager and 2 workers

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox manager1
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox worker1
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox worker2
```

2) Initialization manager:

```
$ docker-machine ssh myvm1 "docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.99.100"
```

3) Initialization workers:

```
$ docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-2xrmha8wyxo471h85sttujbt28f95rm32d40ql3lr3kf3mf27q-4kjyqz4a5lz5ks390k35oc969 192.168.99.100:2377
```

4) Creating env:

```
$ docker-machine env manager1
$ eval $(docker-machine env manager1)
```

5) Creating overlay:

```
$ docker network create --driver overlay --subnet 10.10.10.0/24 my-overlay-network
```

6) Creating service:

```
$ docker service create -p 5000:5000 --replicas 3 --network my-overlay-network --name qwe vaomaohao/app_qwe
```

After this steps service was successfully deployed, but I can access to it only by IP address, not by service name.

Can you explain me please, why?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how did you try to access it?

Comment: @Efrat http://192.168.99.100:5000/load_and_predict, but I want access it by service name, like http://qwe:5000/load_and_predict. Is it possible?

Comment: @Efrat where "qwe" is a service name

Comment: run in the terminal `docker container ls` to get the container name and then run `ping <container_name>`. what do you see?

Comment: @Efrat ping: bad address 'my_container_name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a single solution but you need implemented it. You can use [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/) or [docker flow proxy](https://proxy.dockerflow.com/), and file file hosts in windows or linux.

I recommend you traefik, have easy use. DFP Now project is not a good time.

Hosts File example:
Linux: /etc/hosts 
Windows: c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

> 172.16.1.186   yourdomain.swarm